# MySQL - Referencing an aliased table in a subquery

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a list of most popular users in a project I'm working on. The criteria for being popular is: a) have the most number of posts, b) have the most number of likes on their posts, c) have their posts shared the most, and d) have the most subscribers to their blog.

I can successfully get criteria a) and d) to work well, like so:

```sql
SELECT User.id, User.first_name, COALESCE(Sub.subs, 0) AS subscribers, COALESCE(Post.posts, 0) AS posts, User.profile_pic
FROM blogs AS Blog
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, count(1) as subs
    FROM subscriptions
    GROUP BY user_id) AS Sub ON (Sub.blog_id = Blog.id)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, count(1) as posts
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY user_id) AS Post ON (Post.blog_id = Blog.id)
INNER JOIN users AS User ON (User.id = Blog.user_id)
ORDER BY subscribers DESC, posts DESC
LIMIT 25
```

This gives me the list of top 25 users with most posts and most subscribers to their blog. However, I'm unsure how to incorporate criteria b) and c) into this query, which would probably involve `JOINS` inside the subquery, based on the table structures below:

Blog table:

```
---------------------------------
| id  |  blog_name  |  user_id  |
---------------------------------
```

Posts table:

```
------------------------------
| id  |  user_id  |  blog_id |
------------------------------
```

Subscriptions table:

```
-----------------------------
| id  | user_id  |  blog_id |
-----------------------------
```

Users table:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| id  | first_name  | last_name  |  enc_pwd  |  profile_pic |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Likes table:

```
-----------------------------
| id  | post_id  |  user_id |
-----------------------------
```

Shares table:

```
----------------------------------------
| id  | from_user | to_user |  post_id |
----------------------------------------
```

I have tried the following query, but it gives me an `Unknown column Post.id in ON clause` error.

```
SELECT User.id, User.first_name, COALESCE(Sub.subs, 0) AS subscribers, COALESCE(Post.posts, 0) AS posts, COALESCE(Share.shares, 0) AS shares, User.profile_pic
FROM blogs AS Blog
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, count(1) as subs
    FROM subscriptions
    GROUP BY user_id) AS Sub ON (Sub.blog_id = Blog.id)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, count(1) as posts
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY user_id) AS Post ON (Post.blog_id = Blog.id)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT s.post_id, count(1) as shares
    FROM shares AS s
    INNER JOIN posts AS p ON p.id = s.post_id
    INNER JOIN users AS U ON u.id = p.user_id
    GROUP by s.post_id) AS Share ON (Share.post_id = Post.id) -- Error occurs here
INNER JOIN users AS User ON (User.id = Blog.user_id)
ORDER BY subscribers DESC, posts DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out after a bit of trial and error. It seems to me that you have to write the query in such a way that all the sub-queries should ultimately refer to a related column in the first table in the `FROM` clause (in this case, `x.blog_id = Blog.id`). I'm an intermediate MySQL user, and this is the first time I have had to write a monster query like this (and I know this is nowhere close to all those truly monster SQLs out there!), so pardon me for my inability to use the proper SQL terminologies in my answer. I've been mostly happy with CakePHP and Rails writing queries for me all this while. So, if any of you SQL gurus come across this, it would be great if you could explain this a bit more technically.

Below is how I got a list of top 25 users who have the most posts, have had their posts liked and shared the most, and has the most subscribers:

```
SELECT User.id, User.first_name, COALESCE(Sub.subs, 0) AS subscribers, COALESCE(Post.posts, 0) AS posts, COALESCE(Share.shares, 0) AS shares, COALESCE(`Like`.likes, 0) AS likes, User.profile_pic
FROM blogs AS Blog
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT blog_id, count(1) as subs
    FROM subscriptions
    GROUP BY blog_id) AS Sub ON (Sub.blog_id = Blog.id)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT blog_id, count(1) as posts
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY blog_id) AS Post ON (Post.blog_id = Blog.id)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT blog_id, count(1) as shares
    FROM blogs
    INNER JOIN posts ON (posts.blog_id = blogs.user_id)
    INNER JOIN shares ON (posts.id = shares.post_id)
    GROUP by blog_id) AS Share ON (Share.blog_id = Blog.id)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT blog_id, count(1) as likes
    FROM blogs
    INNER JOIN posts ON (posts.blog_id = blogs.user_id)
    INNER JOIN likes ON (likes.post_id = posts.id)
    GROUP BY blog_id) AS `Like` ON (`Like`.blog_id = Blog.id)
INNER JOIN users AS User ON (User.id = Blog.user_id)
ORDER BY subscribers DESC, posts DESC, shares DESC, likes DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Results in (for example):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id  |  first_name  | last_name  |  subscribers |  posts  |  shares  |  likes  |  profile_pic  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |     Yss      |    Salas   |      243     |   433   |   154    |   545   | 1437ytr_o.png |
|  4  |    Balu      |      V     |      143     |   145   |    45    |   234   | default.png   |
|  3  |   Jessica    |    Nigri   |      134     |   120   |    90    |    77   | default.png   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```